# KMDF driver targeted for Windows 10, not building on Windows 7(SP1) using VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10, driver, windows-7-x64, kmdf

I am creating sample(HelloWorld) KMDF driver using Visual Studio 2017 on Window 7(SP1 and 64 bit). The driver is targeted for Windows 10 and configured for x64 platform.  My project does not compile and throws errors as below -

> UnsignedMultiplyHigh' undefined: assuming extern returning int
>
> __movsq' undefined: assuming extern returning int
>
> __readgsdword' undefined: assuming extern returning int
>
> DbgRaiseAssertionFailure' undefined: assuming extern returning int

But If i configure the project for Win32 instead of x64, it builds fine. I am not able to find the library which is missing in x64 case. I have looked at the project settings for both but can't find the differences .Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Please post the code causing the issue.

Comment: Even if i create a project using "KMDF Empty project template " in VS 2017 and just add .c file having two includes  - #include <ntddk.h> and #include <wdf.h>, i get the same compilation issues.